# ionic 5 get reference of component instance contained in a modal

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I am migrating an application from ionic 3 to 5. In my app I need to access a modal component instance from the class where I create the modal in order to programmatically call a couple of functions on it.

In Ionic3 I used to get the component instance like this:

```
const myComponent = myModal.overlay.instance as MyComponent;
```

but on Ionic 5 the "overlay" property seems to have been removed.

How can I get the instance of my component in Ionic 5? Or is there a better way to call a function on the component contained in the modal?

Comment: Accessing a modal instance so you can access a component inside the modal so you can call a method on it sounds like spaghetti code. Better to extract those methods into a service so you can call the methods from any component with ease.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For sure optimizations can be done here and will probably do but for the moment the task is to migrate from ionic 3 and 5 keeping the same functionalities. Refactor everything while migrating will add more problems to be solved. The question is about a property of HTMLIonModalElement which was exposed in Ionic 3 and its not exposed anymore in Ionic 5, I need, if possible an alternative.